# i want to assign the post to some users and determine if this post is featured for him or not using laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Hi there the following is working well for me, this snippet of code will add new post and assign it to some users.
what i need is to specify that the assigned post is featured or not for a user.

---

### **TABLES**

**posts**
id - integer
title - string

**users**
id - integer
name - string

**post_user**
id - integer
post_id - integer
user_id - integer
assigned - Char[Y/N]

---

### VIEW

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="">

@foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr >
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>
       <div class="checkbox checkbox-inverse">
          <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="{{ $user->id }}">  
       </div>
    </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value=""  name="featured[]"> </td> 
    </tr> 
@endforeach
</form>
```

---

### CONTROLLER

```
$new_post = [ 
      "title" => $request['title'], 
        ];

$assignees =  $request['users'];

$post = Post::create($new_post);       
$post->users()->attach($assignees);
```

What i need is to merge the assignees array with featured array to send the big array to the attach or sync method as follows

```
$post = Post::create($new_post);       
<!-- $post->users()->attach($assignees);  -->
$post->users()->sync([1 => ['featured' => 'Y'], 2 => ['featured' => 'N'], 3 => ['featured' => 'N']]);
```

**I want to add the value of "featued" field in "post_user" table as follows**

```
--------------------------------
post_id  | user_id  | featured 
--------------------------------
   1     |     1    |   Y
   1     |     2    |   N
   1     |     3    |   N
--------------------------------
```

The second part is
How to display the previously checked in "users" and "featured" checkboxes.

**VIEW:**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[{{ $user->id }}]" value="{{ $user->id }}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured[{{ $user->id }}]" value="{{ $user->id }}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: So, what is the problem ?

Comment: i updated the question please check, what i need is to add the "featured" field value to the "post_user" table. for each user. @matiaslauriti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then what you need is:

**VIEW:**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[{{ $user->id }}]" value="{{ $user->id }}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured[{{ $user->id }}]" value="{{ $user->id }}">
@endforeach
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
$inserts = [];
foreach ($request->users as $userId) {
    $inserts[] = [
        'post_id' => $request->post_id,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'featured' => isset($request->featured[$userId])
    ]
}
```

**Explanation:**

Request will send data like:

```
"users" => [
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1
]

"featured" => [
    1 => 1
]
```

where index is `$user->id`. This way you can tell if checkbox for specific user was ticked

Comment: Thank you i did it and your reply helped me a lot. @NoOorZ24

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i make the selected user and featured in html "edit screen" be checked @NoOorZ24

Comment: @Mansourhassan I'm not quit sure what you mean by that. Do you mean pre-checked like: `<input type="checkbox" name="..." checked>`?

Comment: would please check this link, i described my issue with more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876408/what-i-need-is-displaying-all-users-checkboxes-weather-they-have-featured-post-o

Comment: @ NoOorZ24, i finished the create.blade.php but now i want to work on edit.blade.php, so how can i display all users checkboxes in the edit screen with the checked an unchecked