# What I need is displaying all users checkboxes whether they have featured post or not by laravel 8

Tags: laravel

**I have the following 3 tables with relationship ManyToMany**

```
users TABLE
-------------------
   id  | name  
-------------------
   1   |  userName_1
   2   |  userName_2
   3   |  userName_3
   4   |  userName_4
   5   |  userName_5
-------------------
```

```
posts TABLE
----------------------
   id  | title
----------------------
   1   |  title one
   1   |  title two
   1   |  title three
----------------------
```

```
post_user TABLE
--------------------------------
post_id  | user_id  | featured 
--------------------------------
   1     |     1    |   Y
   1     |     2    |   Y
   1     |     3    |   N
   1     |     4    |   N
   1     |     5    |   N
--------------------------------
```

### **Controller**

`$ausers = User::All();`

`$post = POST::findOrFail(1);`

### **View EDIT screen**

```
@foreach ($ausers as $userx)   {{-- --}}
    @foreach ($post->users as $user)
        <tr>  
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="{{-- $user->id --}}"  {{ $user->id == $user->pivot->user_id ? 'checked' : '' }}>  
            <label for="checkbox0">{{ $userx->name }}</label>
        </td>
        <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="featured[{{-- $user->id --}}]" value="1" {{ $user->pivot->featured ? 'checked' : '' }} >
            </td>
         </tr> 
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The problem is that i will display the featured posts with value 'Y' only ass follows

```
--------------------------------
post_id  | user_id  | featured 
--------------------------------
   1     |     1    |   Y
   1     |     2    |   Y
--------------------------------
```

What I need is displaying all users checkboxes [5 users] whether they have featured post or not by laravel 8, and those users who have featured posts show a checked checkbox. i hope i am clear.

Comment: So, what is your problem ? And one simple recommendation, do not use `featured = Y or N`, make it boolean so it should be `1` or `0` and in your code you can [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) it to boolean so you can use `true` or `false`...

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation i will make it. @matiaslauriti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use join on `Users` to make it more simple:

**Controlller**

```
$post = Post::findOrFail(1); // Class names should follow naming convention: POST -> Post

$users = User::select(['id', 'name', 'user_id', 'featured'])
    ->leftJoin('post_user', function($join) use($post) {
        // Using leftJoin "user_id" and "featured" will be null when user wasn't selected
        return $join->on('users.id', '=', 'post_user.user_id')
            ->where('post_user.post_id', $post->id);
    })
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->get();
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>  
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="{{ $user->id }}"  {{ $user->user_id != null ? 'checked' : '' }}>  
            <label for="checkbox0">{{ $user->name }}</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="featured[{{ $user->id }}]" value="1" {{ $user->featured ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        </td>
     </tr> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: many Thanks for your help, it retrieved all the users, and i tried to retrieve the users with status of 'Y' not 'N' by editing your query and adding these lines, but fails.  ->where('users.id', '!=', 1)
 ->where('users.status', '=', 'Y')

Comment: I don't think you should have ` ->where('users.status', '=', 'Y')`. This will limit only to de-selecting users when editing. Also you should swap to boolean column instead of "Y" / "N"

Comment: thank you for your advice. i will change it to boolean.